# What does $u_t - \Delta_p u = 0$ model?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

The heat equation $u_t - \Delta u = 0$ models diffusion of eg. a chemical in some domain. This equation comes from considering $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_\Omega u = \int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot F$$
where the flux $F$ is chosen $F=\nabla u$.

If we choose $F= |\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u$, $p \geq 2$, we get  the $p$-Laplacian equation $$u_t - \Delta_p u = 0.$$
What does this equation supposed to model?

I have heard "it models diffusion at a slow rate if $p \geq 2$". Is it right? I don't see what $p$ has to do with the rate of dispersion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diffusion is proportional to the gradient of the concentration:
$$
-k\,\nabla u.
$$
The minus sign comes from the fact that diffusion goes from higher to lower concentration. $k$ depends on the chemical being diffused and on the medium in which the dispersion takes place. If $k$ is constant, we get the equation $u_t-k\,\Delta u=0$. But $k$ may deppend for instance on the direction of the diffusion (anisotropic medium). Then we get the equation $u_t=\nabla\cdot(k(x)\,\nabla u)$. $k$  may depend also on the concentration $u$. For instance, if $k=u^p$, we get the porous medium equation $u_t=\nabla\cdot(u^p\nabla u)$. In the $p$-Laplacian equation, $k$ depends on the gradient of the concentration. If $p>2$, then $|\nabla u|^{p-2}$ is small if the gradient is small. This implies that the diffusion is slow.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't the PME $u_t = \Delta (u^p)$, because with what you wrote I get $u_t = u^p\Delta u + pu^{p-1}|\nabla u|^2$.

Comment: Yes,you are right, although sometimes $u_t=\nabla\cdot(u^p\nabla u)$ is also called PME.